# Using variable with New-MailboxSearch

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Trying to use a variable that contains multiple source mailboxes for the New-MailboxSearch cmdlet, looks like I need to find a way to use a variable without it inserting double quotes, as I get an error when using a variable the normal way. Example code below..

```
$SourceMailboxes = "user1@domain.com,user2@domain.com"
New-MailboxSearch -Name $Name -SourceMailboxes $SourceMailboxes
```

This gives me the error message *"The specified user "user1@domain.com,user2@domain.com" is not found"*, because it is trying to resolve it as all one user due to the double quotes.

If I enter them manually the correct format works without the double quotes, as seen below..

```
New-MailboxSearch -Name $Name -SourceMailboxes user1@domain.com,user2@domain.com
```

I need to find a way to use the variable without it inserting the double quotes it looks like. Haven't found a way to do this yet.

Comment: That's because you're passing the *supposed to be array* as a single string. Separate it into 2 strings: `$SourceMailboxes = "user1@domain.com","user2@domain.com"`. So, `"This is a single string"`, `"this","is","multipe","strings"`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Abraham. My fault, I forgot to mention in my original post I need it to be dynamic, it may not just be two users, it may be 7, it may 3, it may be 1. I only used two for my example. I have a textbox that a user can type emails addresses into, that textbox goes to the variable $SourceMailboxes. So whatever the user enters in the textbox is what I need to go into the variable. Users are separated by commas, I just need to find a way to leave off the double quotes.

Comment: Very important to have left that out lol you can split the string at the comma: `$SourceMailboxes.Split(',').Trim()` which will return an array of strings.

Comment: Running into the same issue with the -SearchQuery cmdlet now, although I dont think the split will work here. 

Correct format = `New-MailboxSearch -Name $Name -SourceMailboxes $SourceMailboxes.split(',').Trim() -SearchQuery 'Subject:This is the subject'
`

I have a Variable $Subject that pulls from a textbox where the user can type in a subject. I need to include it the same way as above with the SUBJECT:$Subject somehow. It needs the single quotes around it, then Subject:, followed by the variable.

Comment: You mean the parameter? What is the issue? What error does it give you? Do you receive any error?

Comment: That's a separate issue on it's own. If you want the variable to *interpolate*, it needs to be in double quotes. Using single quotes reads the string *as-is*: `"'$subject'"` <- take note of the single quotes inside the doublequotes. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I only have it in single quotes above because that is the correct format that works if I key it in manually, I thought it would help if I provided the working example. So basically I have this... `$Subject = "This is my subject"` and I need it to go after the : in the above example. Using no quotes does not work as it gives me the error **The query of mailbox search 'TestSearch' is invalid. Details: The property keyword isnt supported**. If I use single quotes, the command works, but the search query becomes **Subject:$Subject**, like you mentioned above.

Comment: I am not understanding the situation. A string is a string, therefore single and double quotes are essentially the same with the exception of double quotes expanding variables: `"subject: $subject"` should work.

Comment: I thought that would work also, unfortunately when I use the double quotes I get the same error as I mentioned above. Code as follows `New-MailboxSearch -Name $Name -SourceMailboxes $SourceMailbox.Split(',').Trim() -TargetMailbox $TargetMailbox -SearchQuery "Subject:$Subject"`

Comment: There's something that you're leaving out. Just not sure what since I can't see your screen. Not sure how `$subject` gets populated here

Comment: Link to screenshot, perhaps this will help. [Error Message](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgBAbImA7NSlgZpVvTy6ocwLd6wM2A)

Comment: You already have "subject" in the string. So, it's translating it to: `"Subject:Subject:Term Access LANID: H2..."`. It should just be `-SearchQuery $Subject`. Also, is that LANID supposed to be there?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, even when I take "subject:" out of the variable it still produces the same error using the double quotes, and yes, the LAN-ID is supposed to be there as that is the subject I am trying to search for. New screenshot here with updated code. [Screenshot](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgBAbImA7NSlgZpXUzAO1qCNIpRF_w?e=HkANjB)

Comment: I just tested the same code with removing the colon from the variable, looks like that worked correctly, so the colon is throwing it off I assume here. I guess I could fix this by simply leaving special characters out of the string.